# Error while using Room in android : error 2067 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I used the room database to save objects of type notification . So I implemented the three components of a room database . It went like this :

1.
[The entity I implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClRmi.jpg)

2.
[The Doa I implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCFtd.jpg)

3.
[the Database I implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3SGj.jpg)

I got an error in the Logcat that says :
[The error I encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9drM.jpg)

Comment: Please add the code and errors into your question, not just the links, otherwise you'll end up with an [answer like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=answer&oq=answer)

Answer (score 0):

In your NotificationDao interface, add onConflict attribute to insert function. You can choose either Replace, Ignore or Abort option.

for example:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertAll(varargs users:Notification)
```